# Android - sensor or listener is null

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I am trying to implement a sensor listener in my app, and it throws a `sensor or listener is null` error at the `mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);` line. Here is my full code:

```
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));*/
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR);
    sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            double xAxis = event.values[0];
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rotation);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(xAxis));
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor s, int i) {

        }
    };

    mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

I checked and the sensor was actually `null`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT** : The device is a 2nd Gen. Moto G.

Comment: also textView could be null

Comment: @Blackbelt textView cannot be null. Take that as a given.

Comment: can you try two things? check with a if test and output if your sensor or listener is the one that gives the error, right before you make that call

Comment: @NoaNoNym The sensor is null.

Comment: What kind of device do you use for testing?

Comment: If the sensor is null, the code ain't wrong. You only forgot to check if the sensor is missing, always check this kind of things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is the fact that `Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` is not supported on the device. Therefore the sensor was null.